# File constraints on Symfony 4 form doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, symfony, file-upload

I'm trying to add constraints on the file upload field of my form.

Here is a fraction of my Form type:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

class MovieType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('images', FileType::class, [
                'label' => 'Image(s)',
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '4M',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'image/jpeg',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid image. '
                    ])
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

It does add a validation but when I try to upload a 2.5Mb jpeg, the message is the following: The file is too large. Its size should not exceed 2 MiB. and This value must be of type string.

My class is also simple...

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="collection")
 */
private $images;

    public function getImages()
{
    return $this->images;
}

public function setImages($images)
{
    $this->images = $images;

    return $this;
}
```

I only keep the name of the file after it is stored in the MongoDB document.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `upload_max_filesize` value in your php.ini is set to 2MB.
if it's not the case try :

```
'maxSize' => '4000000'
```